# Materialize CSS Preloader loads poorly when loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I'm using Materialize CSS to make a quick personal site. The site has a fullscreen image / hero when you load up but its big and takes a bit to load.

In order to mitigate this I use the Materialize Circular Preloader (http://materializecss.com/preloader.html). However, it sort of jitters, glitches, slides around about 50% of the time I load the page.

I'm using Google Chrome which doesn't seem to have any open issues and it works sometimes. Here is the standard CSS

```
 <div class="preloader-wrapper big active">
    <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
      <div class="circle-clipper left">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div><div class="gap-patch">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div><div class="circle-clipper right">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my script looks like this right now.

```
     <script>
        // $(document).ready(function() {
        //     $('.preloader-wrapper').addClass('active');
        // });

        $(window).on('load', function() {
            $('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
            $('.preloader-wrapper').delay(350).fadeOut();
        });
    </script>
```

I tried loading the image later, only setting the preloader to active when the document was ready, other preloaders using SVG and CSS. I can't seem to figure out why it's so glitchy and all of these solutions fall prey to this also.

Maybe something with keyframes? They all seem to use CSS keyframes.

EDIT: Here is the site https://sarj21.github.io

Comment: From viewing your demo, and looking at the classes you are using, it appears the circle-clipper left is stepping on the circle-clipper right.  Have you tried starting with fewer elements in your pre-loader to see if a simpler set of div's resolves the issues?

Comment: @JECarterII Those are the classes materialize recommends in their docs and removing parts of it seem to just break it in other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it, the issue seemed to be that the banner image was really big (something around 4000 x 2000 something). I made it smaller and everything loads much smoother and I see no issues with the loader :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are clearly hiding/showing elements with Javascript, I suggest setting all elements to `display: none` in your markup, then relying solely on Javascript to show them later.  That should fix those kinds of quirks.  I've used that trick with a lot of success.

Comment: It seems like even I display nothing except the preloader hero and the splash hero (the thing behind it with the image) it still loads choppy sometimes :/